# Why does swapping fail in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I was trying to write a program that would reverse a list in python3. I first tried:

```
def reverse(lst):
    """ Reverses lst in place.
    >>> x = [3, 2, 4, 5, 1]
    >>> reverse(x)
    >>> x
    [1, 5, 4, 2, 3]
    """
    n = len(lst)
    for i in range(n//2):
        lst[i], lst[n-i-1] = lst[n-i-1], lst[i]
```

It failed and the x I got was the original value. However, when I changed my code to this, it worked:

```
def reverse(lst):
    """ Reverses lst in place.
    >>> x = [3, 2, 4, 5, 1]
    >>> reverse(x)
    >>> x
    [1, 5, 4, 2, 3]
    """
    n = len(lst)
    for i in range(n//2):
        temp = lst[i]
        lst[i] = lst[n-i-1]
        lst[n-i-1] = temp
```

Comment: Your original code works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

It works as expected:

```
>>> def reverse(lst):
...     n = len(lst)
...     for i in range(n//2):
...         lst[i], lst[n-i-1] = lst[n-i-1], lst[i]
...
>>> lst = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> reverse(lst)
>>> print(lst)
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

BTW, why don't you use [`list.reverse`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#mutable-sequence-types)?

```
>>> lst = [1,2,3]
>>> lst.reverse()
>>> lst
[3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: Yeah...worked for me now..I don't know what happened there.. This was just a problem I tried to solve.